# glXGetCurrentDisplay() Segmentation Fault (Linux)

Tags: c++, opengl, interop, segmentation-fault, opencl

I'm working with OpenCL/OpenGL interop and have been able to get it successfully working on OSX:

```
props[0] = CL_CONTEXT_PROPERTY_USE_CGL_SHAREGROUP_APPLE;
props[1] = (cl_context_properties) CGLGetShareGroup( CGLGetCurrentContext() );
```

However, when using the X correspondent:

```
props[0] = CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR;
props[1] = (cl_context_properties) glXGetCurrentContext();
props[2] = CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR;
props[3] = (cl_context_properties) glXGetCurrentDisplay();
props[4] = CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM;
props[5] = (cl_context_properties) pID;
```

OpenGL init code:

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

screenWidth  = glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH);
screenHeight = glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT);

glutInitWindowPosition( (screenWidth - width)/2 , (screenHeight - height)/2 );
glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
glutCreateWindow(appName.c_str());

glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glutDisplayFunc(render_s);
glutIdleFunc(render_s);
glutReshapeFunc(resize_s);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyPress_s);
glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyRelease_s);
glutMouseFunc(mousePress_s);
glutMotionFunc(mouseDrag_s);
glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouseMove_s);
```

The init code is called before getting the context.

glXGetCurrentContext() didn't segfault, but glXGetCurrentDisplay() did.

Excluding the interop, why would glXGetCurrentDisplay() seg fault even after calling glutInit()

P.S. Is there a way to explicitly choose the platform/device under OpenGL?

Comment: Regarding your PS: OpenGL is totally plattform agnostic. It depends on system specific APIs to create a context for it. On Windows this is *WGL* on X11 it's *GLX* and on MacOS X it's *CGL*.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was travelling to another country haha.
Thanks, that helps a lot ^^

Answer (score 5):

> fault even after calling glutInit()

`glutInit` doesn't create an OpenGL context, so glXGetCurrentDisplay will fail. You need to call `glutCreateWindow` to actually create a context.

Comment: Actually, I am creating the window.
Is there any other reason why it would fail?

Comment: @Yuuta: Do you call glXGetCurrentContext _after_ the window has been created? Anyway, glXGetCurrentContext should not cause a segfault. Did you try running your programm in a debugger and extracting a stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks again for the help! (I'll update the code to show the OpenGL init function)

I don't have the Linux machine with me, but my code is exactly the same in Linux and OSX except for the properties I listed above and the appropriate header files.

So I think the order of my function calls are proper since interop works on OSX.

As for the stacktrace, I had four lines

?? ()
3 Lines of trace where glXGetCurrentDisplay was called

Sorry I can't provide the stacktrace exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I just face the same problem. What I found is that you need to initialize the glx extensions. I'm using glew for this one so I need to call `glewInit()` after the context was created in order to `glXGetCurrentDisplay()` to work properly.

Check your headers. If you are including `GL/glxew.h` you need to initialize the function pointers in some way. If you include `GL/glx.h`it should work fine.